# JUnitCore Stopping

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I want to stop/destroy a running JUnitCore, which is started with

```
JUnitCore.run(Request.aClass(ClassToRun));
```

Like `pleaseStop()` on the RunNotifier.

Any ideas?

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/package-summary.html

Comment: What version of JUnit do you use?

Comment: I'm using JUnit 4.8 and beeing able to JUnit 4.10.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to provide another simple solution to stop a JUnitCore:

```
JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
Field field = JUnitCore.class.getDeclaredField("fNotifier");
field.setAccessible(true);
RunNotifier runNotifier = (RunNotifier) field.get(jUnitCore);
runNotifier.pleaseStop();
```

Credits to Matthew Farwell who transfered my idea into code.

Comment: Well done. Maybe it is now time to open a ticket to ask JUnit team to add a "getRunNotifier" to JUnitCore implementation ;)

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1:** 
the best option is to write your own `Runner` implementation, inherited from `org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` and declare it in your execution context, for instance as Main Class of a raw Java command line.

Get inspired of JUnit source code (it is really small), mainly [org.junit.runners.ParentRunner](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.1/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.java#ParentRunner.runChildren%28org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier%29) and override the `runChildren` method by your own to get the opportunity to exit the execution loop when a stop command has been triggered.

The factory for `Runner` is `Request`. To start, you invoke

```
   (new JUnitCore()).run(Request.runner(new MyStoppableRunner().aClass(ClassToRun))
```

**Option 2:** 
If using your own runner is not possible in your context (launched within Eclipse for instance), thanks to a `RunListener` implementation registered in the used runner, you can get a reference to the thread running your test case.

If stop command has been triggered, your listener may throw a `RuntimeException` or even an `Error` in the hope it will make the original test runner collapse.

**Bonus**

These two options are basic as the aim is to check a stop condition and do not go on looping on methods or tests classes.

You may want to try to interrupt the test thread if stuck in sleep or wait state. To do so a watch dog thread should be created to invoke `interrupt` on the test thread after an inactivity timeout.

Comment: So I write my own runner and implement a RunListener in the Runner class? Could you please give a short code example on how to implement the RunListener in the runner class?

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know there 's no such method available.
So the first answer should be : impossible...
But with Java bytecode enhancement frameworks nothing is really impossible...
So I could advise you to write a Java  Interface Closeable or something like this... use the Java bytecode enhancement framework of your choice (asm, bcel, javaassist or any other) and enhance the JunitCore class to implement this interface.Once done you will be able to stop this facade for your tests...

```
public interface Closeable{
   public void stopMe();
}
```

Hi,bytecode enhancement is not the silver bullet of course....But forking and patching an Open Source project requires huge changes into your project management... Who will remeber this little patch 5 years and 3 releases later ? Adding a small class to enhance the bytecode to fulfill your needs is a pragmatic but as always not a perfect answer ....I am Ok with Yves that trying to add the feature into JUnit would be the best solution but it requires far more than technicaal knowledge... Of course you may encounter classloading weird problems while using such technique.... For integration testing I would suggest using TestNG rather than JUnit it provides many enhancements while providing a compatibility layer....

HTH
Jerome

Comment: looks good but how do I know which object or thread to call and interrupt. also do you have a good link descriping this topic?

Comment: another questions, are there any drawbacks when working with bytecode enhancement frameworks?

Comment: Isn't it easier to create a patch on JUnit source code itself instead of doing byte code manipulations ? Less fun but more efficient when such an open source project is considered !

Answer (score 0):

I needed to stop **all** running processes/threads as I was running executing my test suite from a main method using java -jar test.jar within a Docker image. I couldn't then extract the correct exit code after the tests had finished. I went with this:

```
final JUnitCore engine = new JUnitCore();
engine.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
final Result testsResult = engine.run(AllTestSuite.class);
 if (testsResult.wasSuccessful()) {
   System.out.println("Tests complete with success!!!");
   System.exit(0);
 }
   System.out.println("Tests complete with "+ result.getFailureCount() + " failures!!!");
   System.exit(1);
```