# Custom RunNotifier

Tags: java, selenium, junit, junit4

I would like to know, if I write my own custom `RunNotifier` (and Overwrite the methods from the default one), will this methods like `fireTestFailure()` be automatically called when a test fails?

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier.html#RunNotifier()

Another way to ask: can I use this methods like I would overwrite and use custom RunListener Methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RunNotifier` is called by the classes which execute the tests. It calls each `RunListener` for the test (there can be more than one). If you're implementing your own `Runner`, you may want to implement your own `RunNotifier`, but in general you don't need to. It's the `Runner` which calls the `RunNotifier`, which in turn calls each `RunListener`.

If you are implementing your own Runner, look at [JUnitCore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html), which does pretty much everything you want. And then for each test failure, you would call the RunNotifier. If you inherit from JUnitCore, then most of the methods are already there.

If you just want to be informed of the progress of a test, use `RunListener`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem I encounter is, that JUnitCore can't stop tests (pleaseStop()). So I would like to implement a Runner which calls the RunNotifier which can stop the Testrun. But then again I can't add a RunListener to neither a RunNotifier (addListener etc are Internal Use Only) or a Runner. So my question is, can I handle a custom RunNotifier like a custom RunListener, just overwrite it's function and then they are called automaticly on test failure, success etc.

Comment: No, you can't simply replace a RunNotifier. If you look at the source for JUnitCore (https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java), you can see that the RunNotifier isn't replacable. To use @RunWith or similar, you have to implement your own Runner. If you want to be able to stop tests, that's a specific problem, and I'd ask another question explaining the problem in more detail.

Comment: To be honest I already did:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312021/junitcore-stopping with no result. It would also help if I would know How to add a RunListener to a custom Runner?

Comment: Ps.: I didn't want to replace a RunNotifier, just edit it's fire'x' methods to give a visual output of the test progress. Like you can do with a custom RunListener.